# Popup window to return data to parent on close

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I've got a popup window opened using `window.open()`. What I want now is for a user to be able to click one of 2 links within this new window: "Allow" or "Don't Allow".

When a user clicks one of those links the 'popup' window should close, and return either "allow" or "don't allow" or something along those lines, `true`/`false` would do, to the parent window.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Code:

```
var authWindow = window.open('auth.php', 'authWindow', 'options...');
```

Then just 2 anchors inside `auth.php`?

Comment: did you tried something on your own so far ? You could use modal popups

Comment: Code posted? Although I don't really see the need, haha.

Comment: What are you going to be doing with these values afterwards?

Comment: personally i try to avoid window popups. Normally I use jquery-ui dialogs (or flowtools overlay, or wijmo dialogs) to simulate pop-up behavior. IMO it looks nicer, is cleaner and avoids problems with browsers blocking popups - just a small remark :)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In the calling (parent) window add such JS code:

```
function HandlePopupResult(result) {
    alert("result of popup is: " + result);
}
```

In the child window code add this:

```
function CloseMySelf(sender) {
    try {
        window.opener.HandlePopupResult(sender.getAttribute("result"));
    }
    catch (err) {}
    window.close();
    return false;
}
```

And have such links to close the popup:

```
<a href="#" result="allow" onclick="return CloseMySelf(this);">Allow</a>
<a href="#" result="disallow" onclick="return CloseMySelf(this);">Don't Allow</a>
```

Comment: function CloseMySelf is causing an error because the link is just going straight to # and the window isn't closing.

Comment: @Joey sorry, had bug in my code.. see now. (in JavaScript, `catch` must have following brackets)

Comment: Curious: is there a reason you wouldn't just pass 'allow' or 'disallow' as a parameter to the CloseMySelf() function? What is the advantage to use the result attribute design?

Comment: @SteveK better separation between logic and code, since the "allow" and "disallow" are part of the element itself, as I see it at least. Also gives better flexibility, e.g. if we want to use more arguments in the future, just read them from the element itself.

Comment: This is just going to work if parent and child pages are in same server, rigth?

Comment: @Daniel same domain, yes. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625733/how-do-i-get-around-window-opener-cross-domain-security).

Answer (score 4):

you can use `window.opener` for this.