# capture popup window close for oauth with instagram

Tags: javascript, instagram

Related question: [OAuth (Instagram) without refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397433/oauth-instagram-without-refresh)

#### The Situation

Instagram expects a full redirect for authentication, and then they'll redirect back. I want it to work with a popup.

#### Possible Solution

Open the page in a popup:

```
var authWindow = window.open(instagramUrl, 'authWindow');
```

Then I'll have instagram redirect to a page that closes itself:

```
<script>window.close()</script>
```

#### The Problem

I can't figure out how to find out when the window is closed. The following both don't work:

```
authWindow.onbeforeunload = function() {
   window.opener.console.log('Closing popup!');
};

function logClose(cnsl) { cnsl.log('Closing popup!'); }
var callback = _.bind(logClose, window, console);
$(authWindow.document).click(callback);
```

Alternative suggestions are *very* welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `<script>window.close()</script>` directly, you could call a function in the parent window with `window.opener` and then close the window:

Parent:

```
function onInstagramAuth()
{
  // Handle however you would like here
  console.log('authenticated');
}
```

Child:

```
try { window.opener.onInstagramAuth(); } catch (err) {}
window.close();
```