# Communication between two browser windows: popup and parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a parent window, lets saz M, on clicking a button in M, a popup window is opened. When some option is selected in the popup and the OK button is clicked, the popup should close and in the main window a message should be displayed. Is this possible through javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Popup window to return data to parent on close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276086/popup-window-to-return-data-to-parent-on-close) and many others

Comment: yes, please look at [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp). (I know w3schools sucks but on this subject they are relatively ok)

Comment: I made a mistake, not an alert message, but rather a option must get selected. Like a combo box on the main page should get set based on the value selected in the popup.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

yes, it's possible.

close a popup with `window.close()`

communicate with parent window with `window.opener.postMessage()` (`window.opener` is the parent window object, you can even call a direct named function within it for example `window.opener.funcName()`)

next time please look for existing solution before you ask for one, there are plenty of those.

good luck

Comment: But `window.opener` does not exist in IE, is there a workaround?

Comment: @Reiner, see answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562044/window-opener-is-undefined-on-internet-explorer

Comment: and you can listen to the event in the parent window using `window.addEventListener('message', ()=>{});` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#the_dispatched_event