# refresh main page after closing child page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I have a page in which I include a `javascript` file. in the js file 
i have 2 functions called function `a()` and function `b()`. Inside Function "A" I called the popup to be loaded. After the child popup is loaded I have a function called interactive which makes an `ajax` call. if the result is true I need to close the child page and then call the function "B" in the main page.Below is the sample code. The problem is I am not able the refer the function "B" in the child page and make a call to the main page.

```
function a() {
    var strWindowFeatures = "location=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
    var URL = path of the url
    var win = window.open(URL, "_blank", strWindowFeatures);
}

function b() {
    calling a
    function to relaod the page. //
}


function InterActive(encodeText) {

    url: url
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data === true) {
            alert('record updated');
            window.close();
            // i need to call the function b() in the child page..

        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: So you´r open a new window?

Comment: yes. in child window before closing the popup i need to call the function in the main window

Comment: add an `onbeforeunload` eventhandler for the childwindow that calls the reload function

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775862/return-a-value-from-window-open, especially the "second idea" of the accepted answer.

Comment: Go to parent window and then call the function. This will work only if your parent and child are in same doman. Unless you have to use postmessages. Use `window.parent.b()` if both are in same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in such a way that the window you open receives an [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event that calls your reload function in the parent window.

An example would be the following

```
function reloader() {
  if (!reloader.id) {
    reloader.id = 0;
  }
  document.querySelector('#reloadCount').innerHTML = ++reloader.id;
}

function openWindow() {
  var win = window.open('about:blank', 'blank', 'width=640,height=480');
  win.document.write('<html><head><body><h1>Reloads on close</h1></body></html>');
  win.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    reloader();
    return true;
  });
}
```

Which you can test on [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/axp0svkb/) (window.open is not allowed in the stacksnippets)

Comment: @jaiganesh Could you be more specific on the IE version, for me in Chrome, Firefox and internet explorer the example works (where IE shows me a confirmation dialog, however it updates the reloaded part)

Comment: ie version more than 11

Comment: @jaiganesh And your emulation mode is not set to an intranet site, is it? You are making it hard to provide you good feedback with such little information you are willing to give

Comment: @jaiganesh The basic browser support for [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Browser_compatibility) is IE 9 as you can see from the link

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add function b() in child page so it's easily access,So please check with this.

Comment: How does this help the OP?