# showModalDialog and window.open does not work in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

The project that i am trying to fix was based on IE. At one of the pages users will get city name and city code from an opened pop-up page. Those values will pass from pop-up page to current page. There is no problem by doing this while using IE. However if they want to use Microsoft-Edge, that city name and city code will not pass. When I debug the related javascript code in both Microsoft-Edge and IE, I have noticed some problems.

```
if (window.showModalDialog) {
        returnValue = window.showModalDialog(adress, window, "dialogWidth:700px; dialogHeight:500px; status:no; center:yes; resizable:yes; scroll;yes");
    }
    else {
        returnValue = window.open(adress, "newWindow", "width=700, height=500, top=150, left=150, status=no, resizable=yes, scroll=yes, toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, menubar=no, location=no");
    }

    if (returnValue == null) returnValue = "";
    
    if (returnValue != "") {
        var split2 = returnValue.split("£");
        window.document.getElementById(knt + "txtKod").value = split2[0];
        
        
    /*
    ...................................
    */
    }
```

In this piece of code; IE fires `returnValue` under `if (window.showModalDialog)` and a pop-up page is opened. It allows users to select city code and city name and passes those values to current page with this `returnValue`. However, in Microsoft-Edge, that `returnValue` returns `undefined` and it fires the  `returnValue = window.open` in `else` section. But in this time it does not wait users to select city name and city code and it passes to `if (returnValue == null) returnValue = "";` section. So, returnValue eventually does not return an expected value. What I wonder is, are there any alternative for `window.showModalDialog` and `window.open` or do I need to add something.

Comment: Does [Return a value from window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775862/return-a-value-from-window-open) help?

Comment: I think it is not. The problem is window.open does not wait user's selection to city name and city code (to get the value) like window.showModalDialog.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have checked your suggestion again and I found the solution. Suggestion in this link worked for me.

Comment: I'm glad that worked out. I think that if you accept the duplicate suggestion, it will close the question for you.