# Invoke controller method from JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

How can I invoke a method from a controller of another model?

I.e.: I have a popup jsp, where a search button opens another popup with a form (this is binded to another model). In this new popup I can search for an address, which will be returned to the popup before. Any ideas, how this can work?

Thanks.

Comment: can you share what u have done so far?

Comment: after search button opens another popup with a form, do some action then get the value from the controller and return that value to previous popup using java script or jquery, so your address will be come in first popup.

Comment: see this link how to do with java script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276086/popup-window-to-return-data-to-parent-on-close