# How to get a parameter from a popup window on close

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, popup

I need to get an URL param when a popUp is closed.

For now I`ve tried this:

```
var win, checkConnect;    
win = window.open('some url', 'popup', 'width=900, height=600, top='+top+', left='+left);
      checkConnect = setInterval(function() {
        if (!win || !win.closed){
          console.log('Still Open');
          console.log(win.location.href);
        } else{
          console.log('Closed');
          console.log(win.location.href);
        }
        clearInterval(checkConnect);
      }, 1000);
    }
```

But I couldn´t get any data.

Any idea how to deal with this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Popup window to return data to parent on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276086/popup-window-to-return-data-to-parent-on-close)

Comment: @LGSon nope it isn't work here.