# Opening a window, executing a function and closing with a callback

Tags: javascript

So, i want open window, do stuff there using extension and closes page with sending callback status. I want it to work like this :

```
let page = window.open('https://_PAGE_.com', 'mywindow', 'menubar=1,resizable=1,width=250,height=250');
function check() {
    if (page.closed) {
        Console.log(`Status: ${page.STATUS_CALLBACK}`);
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
let interval = setInterval(function() {
    check();
}, 100);
```

**STATUS_CALLBACK** wants to send from the page it opens and execute the extension code

Answer (score 1):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276310/17570866) on how to return data to parent on closing pop-up window.

Comment: that's what I meant, thank you so much for sending this